# else statement of Datatable

Tags: c#

```
string sql = "select * from customer where name like '" + textBox2.Text + "%'";
string sql2 = "select * from customer";

if (textBox2.Text.Length > 0)
{
    DataTable dt = CarDatabase.executeSelect(sql);
    DataTable dt2 = CarDatabase.executeSelect(sql2);

    if (dt == null)
    {
        dataGridView2.DataSource = dt2;
        MessageBox.Show("There's no result with " + textBox2.Text);
    }
    else if (dt != null)
        dataGridView2.DataSource = dt;
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please fill the textbox");
}
```

I try to do "if `like` has some result, show it in `DataGrid`". There's no problem with that. However, when `like` finds nothing in the database, the `DataGrid` stays old. However, if after searching there is no result, the `DataGrid` is empty.

Comment: You must run `.DataBind()` on the grids. And you must provide an `EmptyDataTemplate` to have something shown when there's no data.

Comment: In the interest of efficiency, I would suggest only executing the second Select only if the first one doesn't return anything, ie, move the .executeScalar(sql2) into the IF statement.

Comment: Please use parameters instead of just pasting the .Text of a TextBox. What if the user types `%' delete from customer --` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it is a good practice to use a stored procedure than injecting sql query from the code.

I would have created a procedure something like this...

```
Create Procedure GetCustomers(@name varchar(100))
AS 
BEGIN
 select * from customer  where Name like (ISNULL(@name,Name))
END
```

However while passing value to the @name parameter, you need to append '%' to it. If textbox value is empty then pass null to @name. This query will return all customer if textbox value is empty else the requested customers.

Answer (score 1):

```
string sql = "select * from customer where name like '" + textBox2.Text + "%'";
string sql2 = "select * from customer";

if (textBox2.Text.Length > 0)
{
    DataTable dt = CarDatabase.executeSelect(sql);
    DataTable dt2 = CarDatabase.executeSelect(sql2);

    if (dt == null)
    {
        dataGridView2.DataSource = dt2;
        dataGridView2.DataBind();
        MessageBox.Show("There's no result with " + textBox2.Text);
    }
    else if (dt != null)
    {
        dataGridView2.DataSource = dt;
        dataGridView2.DataBind();
    }
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please fill the textbox");
}
```

Comment: databind gives error :S Error 1 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' does not contain a definition for 'DataBind' and no extension method 'DataBind' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @MertMETİN so replace with **Bind()**

Answer (score 0):

You must have to use `DataBind()`

do the below line in your if else block as

```
dataGridView2.DataBind();
```

Updated:

```
           if (dt == null)
            {
                DataTable table = new DataTable();
                dataGridView2.DataSource = table ;
                MessageBox.Show("There's no result with " + textBox2.Text);
            }
```